# How to universally enable scrolling on website that disabled scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to quickly and universally re-enable scrolling on a website that has disabled scrolling with JavaScript? (Given that there is actually content to scroll through)

The scrolling works when JavaScript is disabled and with JavaScript enabled.

`window.scrollBy(0, 100)` works fine but not when bound to any key or mouse scroll.

Comment: Highly depends on how it was disabled. Get that first.

Comment: Is this your own website? Or you're trying to do this on someone elses'?

Comment: Probably by setting `overflow: auto` on the `body` element. You could test this with `document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'`, or just set it as a CSS style in dev tools.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer irregardless of how it was disabled window.scrollBy(0,100) is working for me on all of the test sites so I am trying to figure out an effective way to assign this to a key button or scroll wheel.

Comment: What about web sites where `window.scrollBy(0,100)` does *not* work?

Comment: Just "regardless", without the "ir-".

Comment: Some uses: `position: fixed` on the document. (some times of NY)

Comment: Is there a way to set javascript/css code like "overflow: visible" permanently for a website domain like Linkedin.com? That way, you don't have to edit element inspector every time you visit that website

Comment: @BryanDowning I love you for this succinct response that finally allows me to regain scrolling, um... for reasons. It takes a humble champion to answer in the comments.

Comment: I ran into this problem on Stereogum blocking the content to try to get me to disable my adblocker. I found a `noscroll` attribute in the body tag, deleted the div overlaying the article, and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 249):

In a browser like Chrome etc.:

1. Inspect the code (for e.g. in Chrome press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>);
2. Set `overflow: visible` on `body` and/or `html` element (for e.g., `<body style="overflow: visible">`)
3. Find/Remove any JavaScripts that may routinely be checking for removal of the `overflow` property:

- To find such JavaScript code, you could for example, go through the code, or click on different JavaScript code in the code debugger console and hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on your keyboard to remove it.
- If you're having trouble finding it, you can simply try removing a couple of JavaScripts (you can of course simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo whatever code you delete, or hit refresh to start over).

Comment: Stalking those LinkedIn profiles Incognito mode unsigned in? It's console time baby. `<body>`: `☐ o̶v̶e̶r̶f̶l̶o̶w̶:̶ ̶h̶i̶d̶d̶e̶n̶`; the `<section>` overlay can go; finally *div#advocate-model*: `☐ b̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶-̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶:̶ ̶r̶g̶b̶a̶(̶0̶,̶0̶,̶0̶,̶0̶.̶5̶)̶`. 1, 2, and ... Poof!

Comment: In addition to setting `overflow: visible`, I also had to delete `position: fixed`. Thanks!

Comment: I've been on sites where you have to delete  inline styles `style="overflow:hidden"` from the body tag.

Comment: Instead of finding the java script I just followed this quick trick to disable java script entirely and that worked for me: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/disable

Comment: Adding `overflow: visible` also worked to re-enable `window.scrollBy` on sites for which it inexplicably doesn't work - although I also deleted all classes on the body for good measure.

Comment: Found also some pages that are putting `overflow: hidden` style on the `<html>` tag itself at the top of page. Turn it into `overflow: visible` too.

Comment: Not just the body tag, check all the tags including <html>.

Comment: Is there a way to permanently set this for each website domain. I.e., whenever you visit LinkedIn.com like @Leo said, automatically set "overflow: visible"? Each time I visit a new link/profile, I have to re-do the steps which can be annoying.

Comment: Here is a bookmarklet you can use to accomplish this:

`javascript:(function(){var r="html,body{overflow:auto !important;}"; var s=document.createElement("style"); s.type="text/css"; s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r)); document.body.appendChild(s); void 0;})();`

Answer (score 95):

Just thought I would help somebody with this.

Typically, you can just paste this in console.

`$("body").css({"overflow":"visible"});`

Or, the javascript only version:

`document.body.style.overflow = "visible";`

Edit: Joshua Goldberg's code from a comment reply:

> I found a similar, bookmarkletable script that did work in this very helpful [QA answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1132323) that did:

```
var r="html,body{overflow:auto !important;}"; 
var s=document.createElement("style"); 
s.type="text/css"; 
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r)); 
document.body.appendChild(s); 
void 0;
```

Comment: When this didn't work on one particular page, I found a similar, bookmarkletable script that did work in this very helpful [QA answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1132323) that did: `var r="html,body{overflow:auto !important;}"; var s=document.createElement("style"); s.type="text/css"; s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r)); document.body.appendChild(s); void 0;`   The linked page also suggests trying to disable sites from disabling scrollbars by setting `dom.disable_window_open_feature.scrollbars` to true in about.config.

Comment: ^ Just want to clarify that this (the comment right above mine, not the parent post) still works in the latest version of Firefox (Developer Edition). None of the other examples worked for me... this one did! Thank you very much @JoshuaGoldberg !

Comment: To make a bookmarklet, past the following into the URL section:
`javascript:(function(){
var r="html,body{overflow:auto !important;}"; 
var s=document.createElement("style"); 
s.type="text/css"; 
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r)); 
document.body.appendChild(s); 
void 0;
})();`

Comment: I'd like to suggest also disabling window.scroll function to prevent website forcibly scroll you all the way up:
`javascript:(function(){var r="html,body{overflow:auto !important;}"; var s=document.createElement("style"); s.type="text/css"; s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r)); document.body.appendChild(s); window.scroll = function(){}; })();`

Answer (score 61):

adding `overflow:visible !important;` to the body element worked for me.

Comment: The OP requested javascript. This is CSS.

Comment: @LiranFunaro Your point? This CSS can be inserted via JavaScript: `document.body.style.overflow = "visible !important";`

Comment: Here's your answer, @LiranFunaro

Comment: Worked for me:

$("body").style = "overflow:visible !important;"

Answer (score 39):

You can paste the following code to the console to scroll up/down using the a/z keyboard keys. If you want to set your own keys you can visit [this](http://keycode.info/) page to get the keycodes

```
function KeyPress(e) {
  var evtobj = window.event? event : e
  if (evtobj.keyCode == 90) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 100) 
  }
  if (evtobj.keyCode == 65) {
    window.scrollBy(0, -100) 
  }
}

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
```

Comment: This is perfect

Comment: Why not WSAD (87, 83, 65,68) or the arrow keys (38, 40, 37, 39)? Note: The Z key has different location in QWERTY and QWERTZ layouts. Note2: See @Héctor Quintero's anwser for the mouse wheel solution.

Answer (score 9):

Select the Body using chrome dev tools (Inspect ) and change in css overflow:visible,

If that doesn't work then check in below css file if html, body is set as overflow:hidden , change it as visible

Answer (score 6):

One last thing is to check for Event Listeners > "scroll" and test deleting them.

Even if you delete the Javascript that created them, the listeners will stick around and prevent scrolling.

Comment: For some sites that has a content wall, even if you deleted the HTML of the wall, enable `overflow` by setting to `scroll` you still can't scroll due to some JS scripts. This method identifies the event listeners, and once I delete them, poof!

Answer (score 6):

With Chrome, one way to automatically re-enable scrolling on a website is to [download the Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), then add [this script (click "Install this script").](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/387702-scroll-bar-enabler)

In general, if you have a URL for a script where the URL ends in *.user.js* and have Tampermonkey installed, you can paste it into Chrome's Omnibox to install the script. More ways to install scripts with Tampermonkey can be found [here.](https://www.tampermonkey.net/faq.php?version=4.11&ext=dhdg&updated=true#Q102)

Answer (score 4):

Try ur code to add 'script' is last line or make test ur console (F12) enable scrolling

```
<script>
(function() {
  for (div=0; div < document.querySelectorAll('div').length; div++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('div')[div].style.overflow = "auto";
  };
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be another way, based on @Future Sim answer

```
addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
    window.scrollBy(0, event.deltaY);
});
```

Just paste it and you will be able to use your mouse wheel

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null
window.ontouchmove = null 
window.onwheel = null
```

Comment: This may not always work if there's a polling script reassigning values to any of those, but good option!

Comment: @designcise that would be very devious of them. You can always poll faster, though. :)

Comment: @AdamThompson I've actually seen some sites do that .. especially some sites that are very hell-bent on showing you ads

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use your browser's developer tools to modify the website's CSS code. You can do this by right-clicking on the page and selecting "Inspect" or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I on Windows or Command+Shift+I on Mac. Then, find the CSS code responsible for the disabled scrolling and delete it or modify it to enable scrolling.

For example, the [Prisma](https://www.prismaimaging.com/invest/) website may have disabled scrolling by setting the "overflow" property to "hidden" on the body or container element. To enable scrolling, you could modify the CSS code to set "overflow" to "auto" or "scroll".

However, it's worth noting that disabling scrolling on a website is often done intentionally for user experience or design reasons, so enabling scrolling may have unintended consequences.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 1):

Important  things to know about `overflow`
`overflow-x: hidden;` means can't scroll using horizontal (left to right) axis.
`overflow-y: hidden;` means can't scroll in vertical (up and down) axis.
`overflow: hidden;` you can't scroll neither vertical nor horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking to enable with inspect element for ad popup or signup pop

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
```

Answer (score 0):

You Probably Copied Some CSS Code Without Checking It

Just Scroll In The CSS Until You Find  A html{} And/Or Body{}
If Any Of Those Contain:
overflow:hidden;
Then Change It To:
overflow:visible;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me was disabling the `position: fixed;` CSS.