# How can I unable scroll in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I created navbar on my project I noticed that I can scroll on the website

[image]

and what I decided to do is to can noscroll function when the user will open navbar

```
function noscroll() {
  window.moveTo(0, 0);
}

function menutoggle() {
  if (menuItems.style.maxHeight == '0%') {
    menuItems.style.maxHeight = '30%';
    window.addEventListener('scroll', noscroll);
  } else {
    menuItems.style.maxHeight = '0%';
    // How can I unable to scroll here?
  }
}
```

Comment: When/how is `menutoggle` function called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable scrolling on website that disabled scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360138/how-to-enable-scrolling-on-website-that-disabled-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

one solution can be:
while nav is open wrap it with another div and then make that div position absolute. Hence it will be outside of the document flow. then give it a height of 100vh width 100vw. After that place, your main nav bar as you like inside the parent div.

Comment: but how with JS? what is just standart scroll function of JS?

Comment: do a if check when the nav is open then listen for event scroll

Answer (score 1):

This would work I suppose:

```
function noScroll() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', noScroll)
```

Comment: yes once again it works, but when I close the navbar than I cant scroll :(

Comment: In the function, you should check if the navbar is expanded then. Have a boolean variable, assign its value to true when the navbar is expanded and false when contracted. Then, check if navbar is expanded inside the function noScroll.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value to scroll, the overflow is clipped and a scrollbar is added to scroll inside the box. Note that this will add a scrollbar both horizontally and vertically (even
if you do not need it):

```
overflow: scroll;
```

[use of overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_overflow.asp#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20overflow%20property%20when%20you,want%20to%20have%20better%20control%20of%20the%20layout.)